# Compiling error with gslwrapper

Tags: c++

I want to compile the files provided by http://gslwrap.sourceforge.net/. In the file "vector_source.h" there is a special macro (specifying an include file) `gsl_vector#typeext#.h`. What does this mean? When I want to compile this file, I get the error "fatal error: gsl/gsl_vector#typeext#.h: No such file or directory". How can I circumvent this? As I do not know anything about the macro, I am lost at the moment.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have skipped a pre-build script `generate`. I am considering this from viewing the GSLWrap's file [`generate`](https://github.com/lrse/exploration/blob/master/gslwrap/generate) on GitHub. It looks like it can translate `#typeext#` to something else using `sed`. However, I am not able to find any documentation for that file.